# Types of DICOM image formats

Tags: dicom

I am aware of single frame and multi-frame dicom image files. I want to know about a cine dicom image, and are there any other dicom image formats.

Comment: image data may be a single frame ,  multi-frame (cine loop),  there are no other physical  types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mention, and Alon mentions in his comment, the DICOM file format supports single frame and multi-frame pixel data.  A "Cine" DICOM file (typically an Ultrasound file) is simply a multi-frame DICOM file.  The format for pixel data (singe vs. multi frame) is constrained by the Service Object Pair (SOP) Class that the DICOM file is implementing.

DICOM files can then be encoded in different uncompressed and compressed transfer syntaxes.  for compressed transfer syntaxes, DICOM defines an encoding that allows both single and multi-frame pixel data.  Among the supported transfer syntaxes are standard and lossless Jpeg, Jpeg-LS, Jpeg 2000, and MPEG.  Note that the MPEG format is used for encoding video, and this is technically encoded as multi-frame pixel data.

Comment: How is it possible to change some specific pixel values of each frame of a Multi-Framed dicom image? 

If possible please help me as per the question I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001042/modifying-a-dicom-image-and-saving-it-as-raw-data/15004438#15004438

Answer (score 2):

Normally two types of Dicom File

1) Single Frame 

2)Multi File 

But I have seen SR Modality file which is structured report for Dicom

And another 3D slices for 3d rendering single dicom file.

Answer (score 1):

DICOM (which stands for Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine) is a standard that discusses a number of topics related to medical imaging. There is only one DICOM image format ([this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM#Data_format) is a good short summary), but there are various types of DICOM objects that can be represented using that format. In DICOM language, those objects are called "Information Objects". [Part 3 of the standard](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/PS3.3.html) defines all of the objects that are included in the standard. Other than images, DICOM can be used to encode such versatile objects as text reports, waveforms, voice audio, and much much more, but it is likely that you will not need to know how to handle all of those objects (for some of them, you may not even be able to find samples!).

If you really want to learn this subject, I recommend [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642108495) as a very accessible introduction to "everything DICOM".

Answer (score 0):

Cine is not a format, as other's have mentioned a Dicom file can be organized as single-frame or multi-frame, but the image encoding can be any: JPEG, RAW, JPEG2000, etc.

Nowadays there are video encodings like MPEG4.