# Modifying a dicom image and saving it as raw data?

Tags: matlab, dicom

Here is the matlab data, where I'm trying to modify the dicom image pixels.

The dicom image is of 4D, 3d for the Rgb image and other dimension represents the fames. I take each frame and I modify the some specific pixel values and I try to save them whole dicom image data in raw format.

The reason why I'm saving it in raw format is that I want to use this data as file in dcmodify command of dcmtk. So, my first question is, am I saving the raw data in correct format? If not, kindly suggest me how I should do so. Moreover, do you know whether or not dcmodify command dcmtk can handle 4d data like in this case or it can only modify just one single frame? Thanks.

```
clc
clear all
close all
img=dicomread('Bad001_2CH_01_anon.dcm');
%%implay(img);
[rows,columns,colors,frames]=size(img);
for i=1:frames
    img(1:25,:,:,i)=0;
    disp(i);
    figure(1)
    imshow(img(:,:,:,i))
end
fid=fopen('image.raw','w+');
cnt=fwrite(fid,img,'uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [gdcmimg](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmimg.html) and or [gdcmraw](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmraw.html) depending on what you really want to do

Comment: Thanks for what you have said, it's already useful for single frame dicom images, but I have not managed to do it yet with multiple frame images.

Comment: You may want to run first `gdcmconv --raw` before gdcmraw and/or gdcmimg.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need raw data to use dmtk: "[dcmodify is a tool that allows to modify, insert and delete tags and items in DICOM files.](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-dcmrt/dcmodify.html)"

Furthermore, raw data is desirable in very few and specific situations, as some metadata in the file saying what is in there and how it is stored helps a lot when a program has to read the information.

I've never used dmkt, but I guess that you should read the data with dicomread (as you do), modify it (as you do), and then save it as DICOM again with [dicomwrite](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/dicomwrite.html)

To preserve the metadata in the DICOM you also need to extract the metadata with [dicominfo](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/dicominfo.html), so you can put it back when you save the file.

```
img = dicomread('originalfile.dcm');
metadata = dicominfo('originalfile.dcm');

% do something with the img

% save altered DICOM with metadata
dicomwrite(img, 'processedFile.dcm', metadata, 'CreateMode', 'copy');
```

Then you can call:

```
dcmodify [options] writtenDicomFile
```

where *writtenDicomFile* is the name you used to save the file, and the [options] specify how are you altering the file.

Comment: I'm making it as Raw data is because the documentation says "-if  --insert-from-file:
       dcmodify -if "PixelData=pixel.raw" file.dcm
       Inserts the content of file 'pixel.raw' into the PixelData element
       of 'file.dcm'.  The contents of the file will be read as is.
       OW data is expected to be little endian ordered and will be
       swapped if necessary.  No checks will be made to ensure that the
       amount of data is reasonable in terms of other attributes such as
       Rows or Columns.
"

Comment: If possible kindly say how I should proceed on this matter.

Comment: Thanks, but dicomwrite in matlab totally changes the private fields because it doesn't understand them. I need to keep the private fields intact, that's why when I was anonymizing all the the Dicom images I could do directly in matlab, I had to use dcmtk.

Comment: I did as you said, unfortunately it runs to MEMORY error. May because that specific Dicom image has 268 frames.

Comment: Set the 'WritePrivate' flag to true in your dicomwrite statement to keep the private tags intact.